# Convert std::string to Unicode in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, unicode

**EDIT** I modified the question after realizing it was wrong to begin with.

I'm porting part of a C# application to Linux, where I need to get the bytes of a UTF-16 string:

```
string myString = "ABC";
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(myString);
```

So that the `bytes` array is now:

```
"65 00 66 00 67 00" (bytes)
```

How can I achieve the same in C++ on Linux? I have a `myString` defined as `std::string`, and it seems that `std::wstring` on Linux is 4 bytes?

Comment: Your conversion is _to_ UTF-16, your example suggests you want UTF-16LE but what are you converting from? (US-ASCII, UTF-8, ISO-8859-*) and have you chosen a unicode library to use?

Comment: I'm converting from the standard (UTF-16?) .NET string. Also (and sorry, I lack knowledge in this area), I don't use any other libraries other than the standard ones, which one should I use? :)

Comment: I "kinda" hacked it, by declaring an array twice the size of my string, and just setting every [i * 2] character, but that's the LAST thing I want :)

Comment: @hmemcpy: In that case your question is misleading because the string isn't "65 66 67" (bytes) to begin with. I think you need to supply more C++ context for your question seeing as you are looking for a C++ answer. If the string is already in the encoding you want you just need to read the bytes of the string one at a time.

Comment: @Charles You're right, of course! After re-reading the question, I realize now it's not correct - the .NET string is already UTF-16, meaning 2 bytes for every character. All I need is, actually, the implementation of GetBytes... I'll change my question

Comment: @hmemcpy: You can just iterate through the bytes of a `std::string`, a `std::string` is just a sequence of bytes. Alternatively you can use `.data()` to get a pointer to the encapsulated bytes and use `.size()` to know how many there are. **This is assuming that you are storing a UTF-16LE encoded string in your `std::string` because you will have embedded zero bytes in this case.**

Comment: @davka: `Unicode.GetBytes` essentially does a `memcpy` (on little-endian systems): the .NET string is in UTF-16LE, and so is the target byte array. There is no equivalent in C++ since there is no such thing as an UTF-16 string in standard C++03.

Comment: @hmemcpy: The fundamental problem is that a C# `string` is a entirely different beast than an C++ `std::string`, therefore there is no direct equivalent for the `GetBytes` method. So if you ask about `std::string`, you always have to answer first which encoding scheme your `std::string` uses. Where does it come from and where do you need the UTF-16 string? Your best bet might be the ICU libraries or some other Unicode-capable library like Qt.

Comment: @hmemcpy: Be forewarned that doing a "2-byte to 4-byte" expansion to convert each UTF-16 character to a UTF-32 character will break if your strings contain any _surrogate pairs_ (basically an escape sequence in which a _pair_ of 2-byte values is used to encode a single character).

Answer (score 4):

You question isn't really clear, but I'll try to clear up some confusion.

## Introduction

Status of the handling of character set in C (and that was inherited by C++) after the '95 amendment to the C standard.

- the character set used is given by the current locale
- `wchar_t` is meant to store code point
- `char` is meant to store a multibyte encoded form (a constraint for instance is that characters in the basic character set must be encoded in one byte)
- string literals are encoded in an implementation defined manner.  If they use characters outside of the basic character set, you can't assume they are valid in all locale.

Thus with a 16 bits `wchar_t` you are restricted to the BMP.  Using the surrogates of UTF-16 is not compliant but I think MS and IBM are more or less forced to do this because they believed Unicode when they said they'll forever be a 16 bits charset.  Those who delayed their Unicode support tend to use a 32 bits wchar_t.

Newer standards don't change much.  Mostly there are literals for UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 encoded strings and there are types for 16 bits and 32 bits char.  There is little or no additional support for Unicode in the standard libraries.

## How to do the transformation of one encoding to the other

You have to be in a locale which use Unicode.  Hopefully

```
std::locale::global(locale(""));
```

will be enough for that.  If not, your environment is not properly setup (or setup for another charset and assuming Unicode won't be a service to your user.).

### C Style

Use the `wcstomsb` and `mbstowcs` functions.  Here is an example for what you asked.

```
std::string narrow(std::wstring const& s)
{
    std::vector<char> result(4*s.size() + 1);
    size_t used = wcstomsb(&result[0], s.data(), result.size());
    assert(used < result.size());
    return result.data();
}
```

### C++ Style

The codecvt facet of the locale provide the needed functionality.  The advantage is that you don't have to change the global locale for using it.  The inconvenient is that the usage is more complex.

```
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <assert.h>
#include <iomanip>

std::string narrow(std::wstring const& s,
                   std::locale loc = std::locale())
{
    std::vector<char> result(4*s.size() + 1);
    wchar_t const* fromNext;
    char* toNext;
    mbstate_t state = {0};
    std::codecvt_base::result convResult
        = std::use_facet<std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t> >(loc)
        .out(state,&s[0], &s[s.size()], fromNext,
             &result[0], &result[result.size()], toNext);

    assert(fromNext == &s[s.size()]);
    assert(toNext != &result[result.size()]);
    assert(convResult == std::codecvt_base::ok);
    *toNext = '\0';

    return &result[0];
}

std::wstring widen(std::string const& s,
                   std::locale loc = std::locale())
{
    std::vector<wchar_t> result(s.size() + 1);
    char const* fromNext;
    wchar_t* toNext;
    mbstate_t state = {0};
    std::codecvt_base::result convResult
        = std::use_facet<std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t> >(loc)
        .in(state, &s[0], &s[s.size()], fromNext,
            &result[0], &result[result.size()], toNext);

    assert(fromNext == &s[s.size()]);
    assert(toNext != &result[result.size()]);
    assert(convResult == std::codecvt_base::ok);
    *toNext = L'\0';

    return &result[0];
}
```

you should replace the assertions by better handling.

BTW, this is standard C++ and doesn't assume Unicode excepted for the computation of the size of result, you can do better by checking convResult which can indicate a partial conversion).

Comment: Your C-style `narrow()` function asserts that the number of characters was "sufficient", but it doesn't truncate the string.

Comment: Also, in some normalization forms, a single character can [consume up to 6 bytes](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: typo: `wchat_t`; tried to save you the trouble by editing it myself but they don't allow  1-letter edits :)

Comment: If the encoding of the input string is known, then technically speaking, I do NOT "have to be in a locale". Do I?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to grab a small library, such as [UTF8 CPP](https://github.com/nemtrif/utfcpp) and do something like:

```
utf8::utf8to16(line.begin(), line.end(), back_inserter(utf16line));
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually use the [UnicodeConverter](http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.UnicodeConverter.html) class from the Poco C++ libraries. If you don't want the dependency then you can have a look at the code.